# how to insert data from selenium to mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I´m trying to get data from a travel webite using selenium. I can extract the data in CSV but i am not able to insert data into my mysql database.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import unittest
import re
import sys
import urllib
import json
import sys, mysql.connector
import csv
import mysql


user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/43.0.2357.124'}

output_file = open("Excel.csv", "w", newline='')  
class Crawling(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
    self.base_url = "https://www.ctrip.com/"
    self.accept_next_alert = True

def test_sel(self):
    driver = self.driver
    delay = 3
    driver.get(self.base_url + "Search/new york")
    for i in range(1,2):

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(2)

    html_source = driver.page_source
    data = html_source.encode("utf-8")

    elements =    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]")
    innerElements = 15
    outerElements = len(elements)/innerElements
    #print(innerElements,  "\t", outerElements, "\t", len(elements))


    for j in range(1, 20):

            price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li["+str(j)+"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]").text

            headline = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li["+str(j)+"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/strong").text

            deeplink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li["+str(j)+"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[1]/a").get_attribute("href")





            if not all([headline, price]):                                                                          
                print("Header not available " " | " + "Price not available " + " | " + "Deeplink: " + str(deeplink))
                headline = "Not available as well as price"

            else:
                print("Header: " + headline + " | " + "Price: " + price[4:] + " | " + "Deeplink: " + str(deeplink))


                writer = csv.writer(output_file)
                csv_fields = ['Header', 'Price', 'Deeplink', 'PartnerID', 'LocationID']
                if elements:
                    writer.writerow([headline, price[4:], deeplink, partner_ID, location_ID])



if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

That is the additional code that I should enable me to extract it to the database:

```
if not all([headline, price]):                                                                          
                print("Header not available " " | " + "Price not available " + " | " + "Deeplink: " + str(deeplink))
                headline = "Not available as well as price"

            else:
                print("Header: " + headline + " | " + "Price: " + price[4:] + " | " + "Deeplink: " + str(deeplink))


                writer = csv.writer(output_file)
                csv_fields = ['Header', 'Price', 'Deeplink', 'PartnerID', 'LocationID']
                if elements:
                    writer.writerow([headline, price[4:], deeplink, partner_ID, location_ID])

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect\
    (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd ="", db = "crawling")
except:
       print("No connection")
       sys.exit(0)


cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("TRUNCATE meta;")
connection.commit()

cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE meta AUTO_INCREMENT =1;")
connection.commit()


cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO meta (price_id, Header, Price, Deeplink) \
    VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")''')


connection.commit()

cursor.close()

connection.close()



if __name__ == "__main__":
     unittest.main()
```

But the problem is that it does not extract to the database. Can you guys help me out/give me a hint? Any feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing any data into `execute()`:

```
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO 
        meta 
        (price_id, Header, Price, Deeplink) 
    VALUES 
        (%s, %s, %s, %s)
""", [price[4:], deeplink, partner_ID, location_ID])
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Now I´m facing the issue that I´m passing just one single line instead of the whole data into my database. What I´m doing wrong here?